# Cannot get bootstrap dropdown to collapse

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, nav

So I'm just trying to make a couple nav links drop down using bootstrap, but for the life of me I can't get the menus to retract. They all start off open (overlapping each other) and they won't close (seen below) I just need the dropdowns to respond normally and maybe automatically shut another one if you click a new one. Code:

```
<head>

<title>Flemington Supply | <?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>

<script type='text/javascript' src="support/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href = "bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet" media = "screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="redox.css">

<link href="support/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type='text/javascript' src="http://imsky.github.io/holder/holder.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="support/carousel.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementByClass('changetext').onmouseover.style.color = "#0000ff;";
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class = "nav navbar">
    <div class = "container">

        <div>
        <ul class = "pull-left">
            <li>
                <a href = "#"><img src = "site1/images/flemsupp.jpeg" height = "60px"></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href = "#">Linecard</a></li>         
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true">
                Company <span class="caret"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Invoice Connection</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Credit Application</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true">
                Products <span class="caret"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About Our Products</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Eljer Products</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Legend Product Line</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Closeouts</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Specials</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true">
                Contact <span class="caret"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Recent Jobs</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Recommended Plumbers</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

        <ul class="pull-right ulright">
            <li><a href="#">Get Directions</a></li>
            <li>Call Us: (908) 782-2221</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

ps I know some tags aren't closed/missing but this page is being included in another one

Comment: Take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpWlaOeGZ_4  . This is a really good video about the bootstrap menu

Comment: thanks that was a helpful video but it did not solve my problem. I just cant understand why it would default as open and why the button that sould toggle the menu fail to work

Answer (score 3):

**Potential problem with the CSS:**

Make sure your element with the class `dropdown-menu` is styled with `display: none`, either in your custom CSS or in the Bootstrap CSS file you're using, and that you don't have any other styling overriding that.  (You can use your browser's **[Element Inspector](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles)** to check.)

Here's how it *should* be working, from the CSS side:

The `dropdown-menu` should start out undisplayed.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

Then, when you toggle the dropdown by clicking on your `data-toggle` button, an Angular directive should add the `open` class to the `dropdown` (the parent element), which will style the `dropdown-menu` with `display: block`.

```
.open > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

**Potential problem with the Javascript:**

This wouldn't explain the initial state of the dropdowns, but it's worth checking: It's possible that your Bootstrap JS file doesn't have **[the proper wiring to handle dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)**.  Search your source file (bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js) for `data-toggle=dropdown`; if you can't find that, you're probably lacking the relevant code.